# Send mouse click from Bluefruit EZ-Key

Tags: c++, ios, bluetooth, hid

I have a bluetooth keyboard that has a key that when pressed will lock your iOS device. I was curious to see if I could replicate this functionality.

I connected the keyboard ([Zagg Folio](http://www.zagg.com/us/en_us/keyboards/ipad-mini-4-keyboard/ipad-mini-4-keyboard-folio)) to my Mac and ran a bluetooth packet logger. When I press the lock button key on the keyboard this is what I get:

[image]

...it's just a mouse BUTTON_1 click (down/up) event with X:0 and Y:0 for movement. Easy peasy.

---

Now I'm trying to replicate this event using the [Bluefruit EZ-Key HID](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-bluefruit-ez-key-diy-bluetooth-hid-keyboard/overview) chip. However, my mouse click (down/up) event when sent through come up like this:

[image]

Very close except that it's not being seen as a "Mouse" and there is no location points associated with it. *Which for the record, if I try to send along location change data it never shops up in the packet logger.*

---

I followed the tutorial on how to send a mouse event and this is what Lady Ada had for sending a mouse event:

```
void mouseCommand(uint8_t buttons, uint8_t x, uint8_t y) {
  BT.write(0xFD);
  BT.write((byte)0x00);
  BT.write((byte)0x03);
  BT.write(buttons);
  BT.write(x);
  BT.write(y);
  BT.write((byte)0x00);
  BT.write((byte)0x00);
  BT.write((byte)0x00);
}
```

However with this code, a mouse event showed up as unknown:

[image]

Not ideal. Seemed like I was getting further away from the solution.

---

So I found [this manual here](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/RN-HID-User-Guide-v1.0r.pdf) on HID events and their structure. I changed my code to this:

```
void mouseCommand(uint8_t buttons, uint8_t x, uint8_t y) {
  BT.write(0xFD);
  BT.write(0x05);
  BT.write(0x02);
  BT.write(buttons);
  BT.write((byte)0x00);
  BT.write((byte)0x00);
  BT.write((byte)0x00);
  BT.write((byte)0x00);
  BT.write((byte)0x00);
}
```

which I got from the HID manual in the link above which states this structure for a mouse event:

[image]

...and I call the method like this:

```
mouseCommand(0x1, 0, 0);
mouseCommand(0x0, 0, 0);
```

which should be a left mouse button press and release. This only gives me the output from the second screen shot above.

---

I've also tried re-mapping the pinouts of the Bluefruit chip using EZ-Key_Remapper and it still does not work. If someone could please tell me if my code format is wrong or maybe it's something else I'm doing incorrect it would be very helpful.

Comment: Giving a -1 without some form of feedback is not constructive. Please advise what I can do to improve my post. @olaf

Comment: You should not state wrong assumptions! I just removed the C tag, as this is clearly not C!

Comment: I apologize but do not understand what you are referring to with stating wrong assumptions, is it because I had a wrong tag? @Olaf

Comment: About the -1 DV. You apparently suspect me - at least your comment invokes that impression.

Comment: @Olaf I apologize for any wrong assumptions. There had been only 1 view of the question along with your edit causing me to jump to that conclusion. My sincerest apologies.

Comment: Your old and new code snippets appear to be the same

Comment: @aja whoops, you're right. I've updated my question :D